# Change destination ip

Tags: c, linux, networking, kernel-module, netfilter

I'm trying to create a kernel module that forward packets in certain conditions. Now I'm trying to do just a hard code test to forward a packet received in an interface and forward it to another interface. In this test I'm receiving a packet from 192.168.56.101 on eth0 and I want to forward this packet on eht1 for 192.168.57.103. In eth0 my ip is 192.168.56.102 and in eth1 my ip is 192.168.57.102. The transport protocol I'm using is a experimental protocol (253). The following code is just a simplified part of my code:

```
#define XOR_PROTOCOL 253

static unsigned int xor_pre_routing_hook(const struct nf_hook_ops *ops, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct net_device *in, const struct net_device *out, int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *))
{
    struct iphdr *iph;
    struct xorhdr *ptr;
    char sip[15];
    char sip2[15];

    iph = ip_hdr(skb);

    sprintf(sip, "%pI4", &iph->saddr);
    sprintf(sip2, "%pI4", &iph->daddr);

    // Check if is XOR protocol
    if (iph->protocol == XOR_PROTOCOL) {
        DEBUG("(Ogirinal) From %pI4 to %pI4.\n", &iph->saddr, &iph->daddr);

        if (strcmp(sip, "192.168.56.101") == 0 && strcmp(sip2, "192.168.56.255") == 0) {
           //iph->saddr = inet_addr("192.168.57.102");
           iph->daddr = inet_addr("192.168.57.103"); 
           DEBUG("(Modified) From %pI4 to %pI4.\n", &iph->saddr, &iph->daddr);
           iph = ip_hdr(skb);
           iph->check = 0;
           ip_send_check (iph);
           return NF_ACCEPT;
        }
    }
accept:
    return NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

This hook in NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING. I also have a hook to just print source and destination ip in NF_INET_FORWARD, but there is no packet passing through this hook.

I'm testing with 3 linux virtual machine on virtual box, and I enabled the forward option in each vm. Is possible to forward packets in this scenario? What I'm doing wrong and what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: How your virtual machines connect to each other? Do you use Linux bridge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the broadcast ip 192.168.56.255, with the ip 192.168.56.102 the packets were forwarded.